# Unable to authenticate with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am trying to sign in to Firebase on an emulator using credentials I added via the console.

Here is the code:

```
val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                // ...
            } else {
                // ...
            }
        }
```

The `OnCompleteListener` callback is never triggered.

I have followed the guidelines from the Firebase documentation

- google-services json file
- Project dependencies
- App dependencies
- Enabled email/password sign in method

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Gradle file - project:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.60'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle file - app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Plz share gradle files @345

Comment: Have you put SHA key in firebase?

Comment: @Raj I have shared the gradle files.

Comment: Yeah, the SHA-1 key is setup.

Comment: @345 Have you tried to log `task.getException()` in the else part of your `if (task.isSuccessful)` statement, to actually see what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by

- Adding a new emulator
- Enabling Identity Toolkit API in developer console (error visible in logcat on new emulator only)

This solution may be helpful for those of you who are using an emulator and have tried all the suggested answers...

Answer (score 1):

Is your email or password are valid?

You can add 'addOnFailureListener' to see what really happened.

```
 auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // ...
                } else {
                    // ...
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: The credentials are valid. onFailure is not firing either.

Comment: Or you have to update your firebase-auth dependencies to newer version.
Now is 16.0.2

Comment: I have updated to the latest dependencies but the problem persists.

Comment: Did you have added internet permission?
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Can you try to add 
maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
inside your project build.gradle in allprojects -> repositories and then clean/rebuild again

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following dependency in the build.gradle file:-

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

And I also recommend you to use the latest firebase dependencies.

Comment: I have added the core dependency and updated the others but the problem persists.

Comment: Also update google services to classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'

Comment: I did but still no success :(